# How to place rectangle inside image and make hover animation for it in CSS?

Tags: html, css, image

This is what I'm looking for:

[image]

I have cropped an image with my html and css but have no idea how to place rectangle in it. I guess for animation I should use `:hover` option for my `crop` class in div. 
My code: http://jsfiddle.net/8t2hmxmn/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess this will fit your needs, to adjust the height of the details element, just edit the `height:` value inside `.details`

```css
html * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.crop {
  background-image: url('http://cs628119.vk.me/v628119319/10059/Ag3oy3YU6wY.jpg');
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.shape {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  color: black;
}
.details {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  padding: 5px 10px;
  transition: all 1s;
  color: white;
}
.crop:hover > .details {
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="shape">
  <div class="crop">
    <div class="details">
      Yes, this is cat!
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sure here is a **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j2aqmv6r/1/)**, but I think that your issue may be this - you forgot to add `position: relative` to `.crop`